# Gradle Fail to zip the .gitignore and .gitattributes

Tags: java, ant, groovy, gradle, zip

I am trying to zip the the `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore` but no matter how I try they are still not existing in the zip.

```
task packageZip(type:Zip) {  
    from('.') {  
      include '**/**'  
      include '**/.gitattributes'  
      exclude 'build'  
   }  
}
```

I know those 2 files are excluding by default but I have no idea how to set defaultExclude into `false`. But it fails.

I don't want to change the gradle setting of the default exclude since it may affect other tasks. Can you give me a sample?

```
task packageZip(type:Zip) {  
       from "./"  
       defaultExclude = "false"  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That wasn't easy to find, but finally I have a solution for you.

You may use defaultexcludes only in Ant directly (Zip task, or AbstractCopyTask whis it extends doesn't seem to implement that. If it does - please correct me). But Ant does. Therefore go with:

```
ant.zip(destfile: 'archive.zip') {
  fileset(dir: 'dir', defaultexcludes:"no")
}
```

To put that into a task just go with

```
task packageZip << {
  // ant.zip ....
}
```

I hope that helps.